# Momentary 250 Degree Celsius Air Heating Element

Tags: airflow, heating-systems

I am a complete novice and need some pointers for designing a heating element that will be installed in an air duct with 60mm diameter, to heat the air passing through it to 250deg C as fast as possible with low voltage. Once the temperature is reached the heater will turn off for about 30 minutes and air speed can be reduced to a minimum during the heating phase in order to increase heat transfer rtate.

My question are

- What would be the minimum DC requirement ?
- Could capacitors be used to accumulate charge over a period of time that, when discharged, could heat the element sufficiently ?
- What would be the best material type; Kanthal, Nichrome, Ceramic (PTC)
- If ceramic, what would be the required dimensions and design (honeycomb, fins, etc.)
- If not ceramic, what would be the required wire gauge and length and what type of supporting material could be used for creating the spine to suspend the wire coils ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is really too many questions all at once. I think your first question should be "given the design constraints (airspeed, heating time, etc) how many watts of heat do I need?"

Comment: You have a massively underspecified problem.  What is "low voltage (and why)?"  What is the air flow rate, both velocity and mass?  What is the maximum allowable pressure drop?  What is "as fast as possible" really?  Because flowing air either heats up or it doesn't, no one cares how fast it happens.  What does "air flow can be slowed to a minimum mean?  Minimum flow is zero.  Do you have unlimited power?  This might be a fun thought exercise, but engineers solve problems.  We don't make up inputs to solve for.

Answer (score 2):

1. First work out your power requirements.
   $$ P = \frac {m \times \Delta T \times SHC} t $$

where $ \frac m t $ is the mass of air per unit time, $ \Delta T $ is the temperature rise and $ SHC $ is the specific heat capacity of air.

2. Choose a heating wire. Nichrome seems to be readily available.
3. Then choose a system voltage (e.g. 12 V) and calculate the current required. $ I = \frac P V $ where P is the power calculated in 1 and V is your chosen voltage. That determines the minimum current rating of your power supply.
4. Work out the resistance of the heating element. $ R = \frac P {I^2}$.
5. Choose a gauge of wire that is rated for that current and cut to length to give the required resistance. Wind it on a high-temperature insulation comb (see hair-drier) and insert in your pipe.

| Question | Response |
| --- | --- |
| What would be the minimum DC requirement? | See calculations above. |
| Could capacitors be used to accumulate charge over a period of time that, when discharged, could heat the element sufficiently? | Very unlikely given the power required. Direct power is much simpler. |
| What would be the best material type; Kanthal, Nichrome, Ceramic (PTC) | See above. |
| If ceramic, what would be the required dimensions and design (honeycomb, fins, etc.) | No idea. |
| If not ceramic, what would be the required wire gauge and length and what type of supporting material could be used for creating the spine to suspend the wire coils? | See above. |

Comment: Thank you for the constructive answer ! As a novice it is often hard to know where to begin. 
- What benefit would there be to increasing the V. It has to be low for safety reasons, but I could increase it possibly

Comment: Higher V --> lower I. Availability of power supply may be your deciding factor. What power requirement did you calculate?

Comment: I am still struggling a little, particularly understanding the SCH of air and is t the ramp time to reach 250deg C ?  Air source is room condition so between 15 - 23 degC. The application needs to be safe as it will be installed in a bathroom and close to waterr, so I assume I could go as high as 24V.

My fan specs are:
    Volume: 6.12m3\h 
    Static Pressure: 149.304pa (0.021654134psi)
Ducting: 60mm intake, 19mm outlet

Comment: SHC of air is a value you look up. I used $\frac m t$, mass per unit time (kg/s), so you need to calculate that from actual flow rate (and you'll need to look up the density of air). I think you'll need to measure the actual flow rate rather than rely on calculations.

Comment: You should add your comments to your question.